# kernel of $1$-form defines a distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, differential-forms, vector-fields

Consider two vector fields $F_1,F_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and define the distribution $$D(q) =\operatorname{span}\left\{F_1(q),F_2(q)\right\}=\left\{a(q)F_1(q)+b(q)F_2(q),\; a,b \in \mathcal{C}^\infty\right\}$$

Suppose $q=(x,y,z)$ such that 
$$
\det(F_1(q),F_2(q),[F_1,F_2](q))=0.
$$

Why is there $\alpha$ such that $D$ is isomorphic to $\ker \; \alpha$ and
$\alpha = y\, dx +dz$ ?